# SQL insert into ... values (..., select(...))

Tags: oracle, select, insert

I am trying to insert 25 users, user1...25 into `Members` with the same `GR_ID = 2` with command:

```
insert into MEMBERS (GR_id, username) values (2, (select username from USERS where username like 'test%'));
```

but get error:

> 1427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Any advice?

Comment: Everything is in Oracle error message – you're attempting to put value into column, but there are more than one of results returned by subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `values` clause in Oracle, you can only provide comma-separated values.

If you want to `select` one or more rows from another table, you have to use this syntax:

```
insert into <table>(<col1>,<col2>,...,<coln>)
select <col1>,<col2>,...,<coln>
from ...;
```

In your case:

```
insert into MEMBERS(GR_id, username)
select 2, username
from USERS
where username like 'test%';
```

Comment: I wouldn't call a subquery a value -- although it does work if it returns a single row. What wording do you suggest?

Comment: I don't think you mean to, but it sounds like you are saying [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29394/9) doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

The query

```
select username from USERS where username like 'test%'
```

.. returns more than one row. If you limit it to return only the first row, or rephrase the WHERE clause to return only a single row, you should be ok.

Comment: The asker wants to insert 25 users.